# TeamCity hg build configuration calling hg init on repo change detected

Tags: windows, mercurial, teamcity

In TeamCity 9 (windows) I have an existing hg repo that I would like to incorporate into a new TC project.
However I am getting an error when the build agent runs, suggesting that is trying to 'hg init' the repo.
The error message is :
"C:\code\xxxx\"}: 'hg init' command failed.
stderr: abort: repository . already exists! "

This seems like very basic configuration issue, I have performed this setup in older versions of TC..

Updated with more info as requested :

VCS root has a 'HG command path' of 'hg'

The latest build log is :

```
Build 'TestProject :: TestBuildConfig' #7
Started 'Tue Aug 04 12:26:18 BST 2015' on 'PCUKDZKBP32' by 'James (tcadmin)'
Finished 'Tue Aug 04 12:26:18 BST 2015' with status 'FAILURE Unable to collect changes'
TeamCity URL http://localhost:8090/viewLog.html?buildId=24&buildTypeId=TestProject_TestBuildConfig 
TeamCity server version is 9.1 (build 36973)

[12:26:18]i: TeamCity server version is 9.1 (build 36973)
[12:26:18]E: bt2
[12:26:18] : Collecting changes in 1 VCS root
[12:26:18] :     [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] VCS Root details
[12:26:18] :         [VCS Root details] "TestRoot" {instance id=20, parent internal id=2, parent id=TestProject_TestRoot, description: "mercurial: c:\code\TestProject\"}
[12:26:18]i:     [Collecting changes in 1 VCS root] Loading current repository state for VCS root 'TestRoot'
[12:26:18]i:         [Loading current repository state for VCS root 'TestRoot'] VCS root 'TestRoot': [C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.BuildServer\system\caches\mercurial\hg_4258089649368462685] hg init
[12:26:18]E: Failed to collect changes, error: 'hg init' command failed.
stderr: abort: repository . already exists!

[12:26:18] : Build finished
```

Comment: How have you set this up, is the repo set up as a VCS root, or are you using a script to do the pull/clone?

Comment: Yes the repo is a VCS root, I can replicate the problem again with a brand new 'test' repo as well. 
I had a stack trace that bascially says "C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.BuildServer\system\caches\mercurial\hg_-5552273506565482688\.hg\hgrc " does not exist , but if I manually place the hgrc in that location I get back to the original  "error: 'hg init' command failed.
stderr: abort: repository . already exists!".
I even re-installed TC... What I don't quite understand is the need to call 'hg init' I guess

Comment: How is the checkout happening, so you have a build step that's running a script to do it, or is TeamCity handling it?

Comment: Its a Team City checkout monitoring the repo via VCS root.

Comment: What's the HG command set to on your VCS root? Could you edit your question and add the output from the TeamCity build log where it updates the sources so we can see exactly what's going on?

Comment: What settings are you using for the VCS Checkout Options on your build configuration? VCS Checkout Mode, Checkout Directory, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the checkout directory already exists and is not being updated. I think the below solution should be all you need to get rid of this error.

In your TeamCity Configuration, redirect to the "Edit project build configurations" tab where you have set this build configuration.

In your build configuration click on the VCS tab on the left which will show you the attached VCS repositories to that configuration.

On this page there is a small CheckBox which says something like "clean all files before checkout/build" tick this and run your build and it should delete all the existing instances of the repository which was pulled down and download it again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion ,it sounds like it *should* work that way, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue to this and it was driving me crazy.  It was happening on two different fresh instances of TeamCity v9.1.1.

In the end I installed a fresh version of v9.0.4 and it worked successfully each time.

I plan to upgrade the instance to v9.1.1 today and see if the breaks.  So it looks as though it may be an issue with TC itself.